# ZF2 / Doctrine / Cannot remove all elements from an ArrayCollection

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 entities, **Product** and **Category** with a bidirectional ManyToMany association mapping defined below :

**Product**

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_categories")
*/
protected $categories;

// with these accessors

    public function addCategories(Collection $categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $this->addCategory($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category)
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category))
        {
            $this->categories->add($category);
            $category->addProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategories(Collection $categories)
    {
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $this->removeCategory($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category)
    {
        if ($this->categories->contains($category))
        {
            $this->categories->removeElement($category);
            $category->removeProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function setCategories($categories)
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $this->addCategory($category);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

And **Category** entity :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="categories")
*/
protected $products;

// And accessors

    public function addProducts(Collection $products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $this->addProduct($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        if (!$this->products->contains($product))
        {
            $this->products->add($product);
            $product->addCategory($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProducts(Collection $products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $this->removeProduct($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product)
    {
        if ($this->products->contains($product))
        {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

   public function setProducts($products)
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $this->addProduct($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

The problem is : In a ZF2 form select multiple, to select categories for products, I cannot remove the last entry or remove all entries ...

One by one it works, except for the last.

**Edit**
If I delete all elements, removeCategories() is not called.

Any help would be much appreciated

**Edit 2**

I found a very hugly solution to skirt the bug ...

In fact, when the multiple select is empty, it disappear from the $_POST variable ... So, in my Product controller, in the editAction(), I make this test :

```
if (!isset($_POST['main']['categories']))
{
    $product->getCategories()->clear();
}
```

I don't consider this hack to a good solution.

So, if someone has a better solution, I'm waiting for an answer. TY

Comment: Did you try adding a 'cascade="persist"' on the Product side of the relation?

Comment: @Gerard van Helder yes, I tried that on $categories property declaration : `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist", "merge"})` but same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's propably bug in ZF, see:

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4492

and PR with fix:

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/7447

Your solution in **Edit 2** section is the same workaround I'm using in my code until fix will be released.

Comment: @Iku, thanks for this answer, but I'm not using a `Zend\Form\Element\Collection` element here. But `Zend\Form\Element\Select` with multiple property

Comment: @ceadreak That is bug more in `Zend\Form\Form::prepareBindData` method. If you post you select element empty, there is no data for this element in $_POST and it is skipped from hydration. That is why isn't your `removeCategories` method called.

Comment: @Iku, Yes, I saw it in `Zend\Form\Form` class. So, just waiting for a fix ... Or maybe simply overload `prepareBindData` method to set an empty array instead of a null value for an ArrayCollection but how to achieve that without the form structure ...

Comment: @ceadreak You can try this hotfix in issue comments: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4492#issuecomment-24235651

Comment: But the value for categories in `$values` is `null` ... So this condition cannot be achieved `if (is_array($value) && empty($value))`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments above overriding Form->prepareBindData is a solution.

```php
class MyForm extends Form
{
    ...

    protected function prepareBindData(array $values, array $match)
    {
        return $values;
    }
}
```